# Is select 1 from table getting obsolete in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is `select 1 from table` getting obsolete in SQL Server 2014 or future versions for SQL Server; if so, what is the alternative for it?

Comment: Not pretty sure about your quesion but SELECT 1 FROM Table just displays 1 like a normal value which is not a thing SQL Server can eliminate.

Comment: From where you got this info

Answer (score 2):

Personally I never write code like this, but I do see other developer `SELECT 1` in two circumstances.

1. `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table)`
2. `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table`

In either case, `1` can be written as `*`. SQL Server is smart enough to know you really don't need all columns. Following queries do the exact the same thing.

- `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table`
- `SELECT COUNT(PK) FROM Table`
- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table`

It's the same for query `EXISTS (SELECT *)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help if this is a homework.

```
declare @count int
select @count = count(*) from table
while (@count!=0)
begin
    select 1
    select @count = @count - 1
end
```

Comment: I cannot see a relation between your answer and OP question. Could you please clarify it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @sqluser. select 1 from table means OP wants to see 1s as much as the table row count. Straightforwardly the answer shows 1s as much as table row count.

Answer (score 0):

`Select 1 from tablename` gives the answer 1 of no. or row in the table.

By default `*` is used for all column or you define a column with alias.

When you give `select 1` it gives the single record with value 1 as there are no tablename.

When you gives `select 1 from tablename` means it will first fetch the total record and as you choose 1 in the columnlist it will display 1 in all record.

just try

```
select 1
select 1 from tablename
```